# Cannot list directory iOS

Tags: ios, python-3.x

So I downloaded an app on my iPad for python coding (Pythonista). Aside from writing scripts, there is also a python shell. I figured this would be the closest thing to an actual terminal, as iOS devices don’t allow you to open one at will. This is the code:

```
import os
os.chdir('/System')
os.listdir()
```

The error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/524D3A96-8086-400C-A010-F04A5240AD62/Pythonista3/Documents/ls.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.listdir()
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Why is this happening? Also I am able to use os.chdir() when I’m in the ‘/System’ directory to change to ‘/System/Library’ for ex.
Anything helps, thx

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html

Comment: You need to have root/admin tight which can only be provided by jailbreaking